# 10 Year Challenge

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

The hashtag 10yearchallenge is very trendy now, but the use of the compond adjective (10-year) makes it look like it's a challenge that spanned 10 years, however, it's the name of the challenge not an adjective describing it.

I'm very confused about the use of this form and would ask your advice if it's the correct way to say it, and why.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the line you are trying to draw. The name does describe the challenge. Any name describes the thing it's the name of. And the challenge is all about the span of 10 years. Hence the name. Which describes it. So there's nothing to be confused about as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @RegDwigнt we had before ice bucket challenge. The 'ice bucket' is the name of the challenge not an adjective. How would you describe a challenge that spanned 10 years ? You would say it was a 10-year challenge. Can you see the point ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I am having difficulty understanding what else it might be interpreted as. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @ALambentEye 10-hour movie means it's a movie that spanned 10 hours. However, 10 Hours movie, is a movie that is simply named '10 Hours'. So, saying 10-year challenge means that it's a challenge that spanned 10 years (for example someone taking a photo of himself everyday for 10 years).

Comment: And how does that differ from the challenge? Is the "10 Year Challenge" not  a challenge spanning 10 years?

Comment: @ALambentEye not exactly. Did it span 10 years? It just came out 2 days ago.

Comment: Are you asking how we should refer to a challenge that occurs on the tenth anniversary of some event? (*A tenth-anniversary challenge* or *a challenge commemorating ten years.*) Or are you asking if the hashtag itself is appropriate?

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm asking if the hashtag is appropriate, as the usage of the compund adjective is misleading

Comment: You need to describe what this challenge is all about. I don't have a Twitter account, and I am not motivated enough to find out for myself. If users are posting comments, telling you they cannot see a problem, it means you haven't explained  well enough.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the challenge includes a span of 10 years, not that the challenge takes place over 10 years.